# TypeError: Cannot read property '$dirty' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-validation, angularjs-forms

I have an Angular form with name `p24Form`

```
<div ng-form="private2" name="p24Form" ng-show="freqSelect == '2.4'" novalidate="" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">
            <span class="edit" data-pk="private_2">WiFi name</span>:
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="freq2_name" ng-model="ssid">
            <!-- tooltips:  -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to detect if it is dirty or change, then showing my save button accordingly. 
I tried

## Try#1

```
if ($scope.p24Form.$dirty) {
    alert('dirty');
    $scope.showSaveBtn = true;
}else{
    $scope.showSaveBtn = false;
}
```

## Try #2

```
if ($scope.private2.$dirty) {
    alert('dirty');
    $scope.showSaveBtn = true;
}else{
    $scope.showSaveBtn = false;
}
```

I kept got

> TypeError: Cannot read property '$dirty' of undefined

How can I debug this?

Comment: means `$scope.p24Form` is undefined

Comment: shouldn't it be $scope.private2.$dirty

Comment: @epascarello : I just want to check if one of my inputs of my form got touched. Do I need to set a default value to my `$scope.p24Form` ?

Comment: @Jean-MichelProvencher : I believe we should use the name, but please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Ohh okay, let me try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access an input of your form to check if it's dirty. For example:

```
$scope.myForm.inputName.$dirty
```

As you pointed out, you should use the name attribute of the form to access it.

Also you are accessing myForm object which is nothing but form object, I won't be available until DOM get rendered, $scope.myForm will be simply undefined at the time of controller initilization, If you really want to access $scope.myForm from controller then you need to put that code in $timeout that will run $timeout function code in next digest cycle.

```
$timeout(function(){
    $scope.isDirty = $scope.myForm.$dirty;
  });
```

Comment: Since checking for the inputs is a little over kill for my situation since I have 20 inputs, is there a way to check if a form is dirty rather checking all the inputs inside a form. That way is less code, and less check on my end ?

Comment: $scope.$watch('myForm.$dirty', function(n) {if(n) {alert ('dirty'); }});

Comment: That was exactly what I did, and that is how I got this error, and asking this question.

Comment: Keep in mind that mine is not a form. It is a `div` with `ng-form` attribute.

Comment: I added new elements in my answer

Comment: I saw, thank-you for that. So to recap, I got that error because of my DOM is not rendering and accessible at the time, I am trying to access it. Is that correct ?

Comment: From what I see, Yes. However it's tough for me to confirm that since I don't  all your angular controller. If it's working, please mark my answer as correct. Thanks!